# vscode python intellisense doesn't work PROPERLY for some modules

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

the title explain's the problem, the module is tensorflow, recently i had the same issue with numpy also, but adding my site-packages path to vscode `python->autoComplete->extraPaths` fixed the problem in case of numpy, but it doesn't work for tensorflow!

now let me tell you what i mean by PROPERLY:
when i write a dot(.) after module name and then press `CTRL + SPACE` it shows nothing to me but when i type the first letter it starts showing attributes.

[CTRL + SPACE after dot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpkbP.png)

[after typing the first letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEAZe.png)

it's not such a big deal but i just feel want it fixed, and i want to know the reason behind it to prevent such things again.

also my extraPaths in setting.json:

```json
{"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
        "/home/shayan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras",
        "/home/shayan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/",
        "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras",
        "/home/shayan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras",
        "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages",
        "/home/shayan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages",
        "/home/shayan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy",
        "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow",
        "/home/shayan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow",
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for all this is probably because you have multiple python versions on your machine, which messes up the vscode environment.

It is recommended that you use a virtual environment, which is very helpful for using different python versions and installing different packages in different environments.

**How to create and use a virtual environment:**

Create a virtual environment named **.venv** using the following command in the vscode terminal

```
python -m venv .venv
```

Activate the virtual environment with the following command

```
.venv\scripts\activate
```

*PS:* Select the python interpreter in the virtual environment, and then create a new terminal, the virtual environment will be automatically activated.

[image]

Comment: thanks, but it didn't work! i don't think that's the case because everything works fine immediately after typing the first letter! maybe that's a default behavior or maybe that's a bug! do you think i should create a github issue?